# MATLAB code for matrix labeling

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I am having a trouble writing a code for a matlab code to perform labeling for a binary matrix. In my code, I compare the value of the current element with that on its top, left and upper left corner, and if the values match, then I give the element the same label.

The code is given below:

```
clc; clear all; close all; tic;
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

M=10; N=20;

I_b=[
     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
     0     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     1     1
     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     1     0
     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0
     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1
     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     1     1  
];

[ID]=UnionFind(I_b,M,N);

I_b

ID

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
toc;




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function [ID] = UnionFind(I_b, M, N)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

ID=reshape(1:1:M*N,M,N);

for i=2:1:M*N

        if(I_b(i)==I_b(i-1))

            ID(i)=ID(i-1);

        elseif (i>M)

            if(I_b(i)==I_b(i-M))

                ID(i)=ID(i-M);

            end

        elseif (i>(M+1))

            if (I_b(i)==I_b(i-1-M))

                ID(i)=ID(i-1-M);

            end

        end

end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

when you run this code, you will notice that some parts of the zeros and one have multiple lables even though they are connected and hence must have the same label.

Can you please check this code?

Answer (score 0):

You (at least) do not handle cases when two differently labeled areas merges into one area during the traversal. You also have bug with wrapping `I_b(i - 1)`. Use built-in function [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) instead.

Comment: I know...but how to fix it in my code? I don't want to use built-in functions of matlab.